# save current window to use it at resume

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile

i am trying to save the current window in focus event to app properties like this

```
$.profileWin.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
    Ti.App.Properties.setObject("curwin", $.profileWin);
});
```

i am doing this for more than 1 window

but at focus of window i get this error

> -[TiUIWindowProxy encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ea19c00";

how do i save the the current window and have it accessed when the iPhone resumes from its suspended state

Comment: i still could not how to do this. any alternative way

Answer (score 0):

When you try to save a value in Ti.App.Properties it will simply be converted to at string of text. I'm not sure `setObject` will accept anything else but JSON-objects (and a Ti.UI.Window is not a JSON-object).

That being said, saving the actual Window-object might not be a good idea, as the different dependencies might have been removed from memory, when you try to reload the window.

A better approach would be to save the relevant properties of the Window (and other values that you might need to restore the current state of the Window) and the re-layout the Window once it gains focus.